# How to acess form label from a method

Tags: c#, winforms

Following code is the idea of main problem. What i am trying to do is that, when someone press button1, a timer is enabled to change the value of label1 continuously. Now the main problem is i need to access form elements like label, textbox from TimerEventProcessor() but i can not do that. I tried using Form1 formm = new Form1();  but still doesn't work. Nothings shows and I don't get any error either.

```
    static Timer mytimer = new Timer();
    static int counter= 1;

private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{   mytimer.Enabled = true;
    Form1 formm = new Form1();            
    formm.label1.Text = counter;
    counter++;
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

   myTimer.Interval = 1000;
   myTimer.Start(); 
}
```

Comment: Remove the *static* keywords.  Now it is simple, just "this.label1".

Comment: or if your need `TimerEventProcessor` to be static, define a static variable in your application namespace and set it's value to your `Form` instance on `Form` load (ie. write `yourStaticVariable = this` on `Form` load)

Comment: That pretty much defeats the purpose of using static methods. Even if you want a Singleton instance of your `Form1`, the fields and event handler should absolutely be non-static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `TimerEventProcessor` along with the `Timer` and `counter` fields non static and use `this` instead of creating a new instance. It's also not necessary to set the `myTimer.Enabled` property each time.

```
Timer mytimer = new Timer();
int counter= 1;

private void TimerEventProcessor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    this.label1.Text = counter;
    counter++;
}
```